# How to group items by particular column from a tab separated file

Tags: ruby

I have following records in a tab separated text file:

```
sku title   Product Type                        
19686940    This is test Title1 toys                        
19686941    This is test Title2 toys                        
19686942    This is test Title3 toys                        
20519300    This is test Title1 toys2                       
20519301    This is test Title2 toys2
20580987    This is test Title1 toys3                       
20580988    This is test Title2 toys3                       
20582176    This is test Title1 toys4
```

How to group items by `Product Type` and find all unique words in `title`?

**Output format:**

```
Product Type   Unique_words 
------------   ------------ 
toys           This is test Title1 Title2 Title3
toys2          This is test Title1 Title2
toys3          This is test Title1 Title2
toys4          This is test Title1
```

**Update**
    Till now I have done code till reading the file and storing into an array:

```
class Product
    attr_reader :sku, :title, :productType
    def initialize(sku,title,productType)
      @sku = sku
      @title = title
      @productType = productType
    end

    def sku
      @sku
    end

    def title
      @title
    end

    def productType
      @productType
    end
end

class FileReader
  def ReadFile(m_FilePath)
    array = Array.new
    lines = IO.readlines(m_FilePath)

    lines.each_with_index do |line, i|
      current_row = line.split("\t")
      product = Product.new(current_row[0],current_row[1],current_row[2])

      array.push product
    end
  end
end

filereader_method = FileReader.new.method("ReadFile")
Reading =  filereader_method.to_proc

puts Reading.call("Input.txt")
```

Comment: can you give some  sample outputs too?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and what's not working.

Comment: please review updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the grouping, you can use the [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
Product = Struct.new(:sku, :title, :product_type)

def products_by_type(file_path)
  File.open(file_path)
      .map{ |line| Product.new(*line.chomp.split("\t")) }
      .group_by{ |product| product.product_type }
end
```

The beauty of Ruby is you have so many options. You can also check out the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) lib and [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) since this is just a data object:

```
require 'csv'
require 'ostruct'

def products_by_type(file_path)
  csv_opts = { col_sep: "\t",
               headers: true,
               header_converters: [:downcase, :symbol] }

  CSV.open(file_path, csv_opts)
     .map{ |row| OpenStruct.new row.to_hash }
     .group_by{ |product| product.product_type }
end
```

Or use the idiom of creation based on hash keys to remove that call to `#to_hash` on `row` above:

```
class Product
  attr_accessor :sku, :title, :product_type

  def initialize(data)
    data.each{ |key, value| self.key = value }
  end
end

def products_by_type(file_path)
  csv_opts = { #... }

  CSV.open(file_path, csv_opts)
     .map{ |row| Product.new row }
     .group_by{ |product| product.product_type }
end
```

Then based on the hash, format your output as desired:

```
def unique_title_words(*products)
  products.flat_map{ |product| product.title.scan(/\w+/) }
          .unique
end

puts "Product Type\tUnique Words"
products_by_type("./file.txt").each do |type, products|
  puts "#{type}\t#{unique_title_words products}"
end
```